# WCF Performance net.tcp using XMLSerialization

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to resolve a performance issue with WCF in our application. I am retrieving 7500 records from a database through a service, and have discovered the following timings:

- Query Database and create object graph: 6.7 seconds.
- Time from client receives message until rendered in WPF: 2.1 seconds.
- Transfer and serialization (WCF): 90 seconds.

The client uses a net.tcp binding to call the service. The setup appears ordinary, and the service is marked with `[ServiceContract]` and the method `[OperationContract]` and `[UseNetDataContractSerializer]`.

When running ANTS Performance Profiler against the server, I see the following hot path:

```
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, int bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection+TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream+IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(object state)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously)
System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(int bytes)
System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ReadCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessFrameBody(int readBytes, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource+ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(object state)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel+TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, bool cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(bool isOperationContextSet)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(MessageRpc rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSendCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.EncodeMessage(Message message)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoderFactory+BinaryMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, int initialOffset, int maxSizeQuota)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter+OperationFormatterMessage+OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, string action, MessageDescription messageDescription, object returnValue, object[] parameters, bool isRequest)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter+PartInfo part, object graph)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter+PartInfo part, object graph)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, object graph)
System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, object graph, DataContract contract, Hashtable surrogateDataContracts)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
(Unmanaged code)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteISerializable(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, ISerializable obj)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteSerializationInfo(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Type objType, SerializationInfo serInfo)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
(Unmanaged code)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
(Unmanaged code)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
(Unmanaged code)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteISerializable(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, ISerializable obj)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteSerializationInfo(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Type objType, SerializationInfo serInfo)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
(Unmanaged code)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
(Unmanaged code)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
(Unmanaged code)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.OnHandleReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool canContainCyclicReference)

System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectToIdCache.GetId(object obj, ref bool newId)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectToIdCache.Rehash)
System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectToIdCache.FindElement(object obj, out bool isEmpty, out bool isWrapped)
```

Why is the `BinaryMessageEncoder` calling `XmlObjectSerializer`?

Is it normal WCF behaviour that it first serializes to XML, then binary, or it is my service somehow configured to serialize to XML?

I am also exposing the service as HTTP, but I have double-checked that the client indeed uses net.tcp.

I have done a bit of digging, but haven't been able to find any issues. Nor can I reproduce it in a toy example. There are no byte[] properties or anything like that.

Comment: XML does not necessarily mean text. In WCF the binary serialized data is logically represented as an XML tree, but still in a binary form. No XML text is ever generated, except for instance in the WCF service trace viewer tool that will deserialize it to a text representation for debugging.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I did find it odd that it actually would call `BinaryMessageEncoder` if I was using XML serialization. This unfortunately means I will have to persue other avenues. Thanks for your insight - Please make an answer, and I will mark this as resolved.

Comment: I did not make an answer because that doesn't solve your performance problem. Unfortunately, I'm unable to help you with that one as it'll need profiling...